# Scala Function.tupled and Function.untupled equivalent for variable arity, or, calling variable arity function with tuple

Tags: scala, types, shapeless

I was trying to do some stuff last night around accepting and calling a generic function (i.e. the type is known at the call site, but potentially varies across call sites, so the definition should be generic across arities).

For example, suppose I have a function `f: (A, B, C, ...) => Z`. (There are actually many such `f`s, which I do not know in advance, and so I cannot fix the types nor count of `A, B, C, ..., Z`.)

I'm trying to achieve the following.

1. How do I call `f` generically with an instance of `(A, B, C, ...)`? If the signature of `f` were known in advance, then I could do something involving `Function.tupled f` or equivalent.
2. How do I define another function or method (for example, some `object`'s `apply` method) with the same signature as `f`? That is to say, how do I define a `g` for which `g(a, b, c, ...)` type checks if and only if `f(a, b, c, ...)` type checks? I was looking into Shapeless's `HList` for this. From what I can tell so far, `HList` at least solves the "representing an arbitrary arity args list" issue, and also, Shapeless would solve the conversion to and from tuple issue. However, I'm still not sure I understand how this would fit in with a function of generic arity, if at all.
3. How do I define another function or method with a related type signature to `f`? The biggest example that comes to mind now is some `h: (A, B, C, ...) => SomeErrorThing[Z] \/ Z`.

I remember watching a conference presentation on Shapeless some time ago. While the presenter did not explicitly demonstrate these things, what they did demonstrate (various techniques around abstracting/genericizing tuples vs `HList`s) would lead me to believe that similar things as the above are possible with the same tools.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm convinced Shapeless will help you in doing that. I unfortunately don't have the time right now to fiddle around with this.

Comment: My impression is also that along the lines of, this resembles what I've seen Shapeless do, but I'm not quite sure how.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, Shapeless can absolutely help you here. Suppose for example that we want to take a function of arbitrary arity and turn it into a function of the same arity but with the return type wrapped in `Option` (I think this will hit all three points of your question).

To keep things simple I'll just say the `Option` is always `Some`. This takes a pretty dense four lines:

```
import shapeless._, ops.function._

def wrap[F, I <: HList, O](f: F)(implicit
  ftp: FnToProduct.Aux[F, I => O],
  ffp: FnFromProduct[I => Option[O]]
): ffp.Out = ffp(i => Some(ftp(f)(i)))
```

We can show that it works:

```
scala> wrap((i: Int) => i + 1)
res0: Int => Option[Int] = <function1>

scala> wrap((i: Int, s: String, t: String) => (s * i) + t)
res1: (Int, String, String) => Option[String] = <function3>

scala> res1(3, "foo", "bar")
res2: Option[String] = Some(foofoofoobar)
```

Note the appropriate static return types. Now for *how* it works:

The `FnToProduct` type class provides evidence that some type `F` is a `FunctionN` (for some `N`) that can be converted into a function from some `HList` to the original output type. The `HList` function (a `Function1`, to be precise) is the `Out` type member of the instance, or the second type parameter of the `FnToProduct.Aux` helper.

`FnFromProduct` does the reverse—it's evidence that some `F` is a `Function1` from an `HList` to some output type that can be converted into a function of some arity to that output type.

In our `wrap` method, we use `FnToProduct.Aux` to constrain the `Out` of the `FnToProduct` instance for `F` in such a way that we can refer to the `HList` parameter list and the `O` result type in the type of our `FnFromProduct` instance. The implementation is then pretty straightforward—we just apply the instances in the appropriate places.

This may all seem very complicated, but once you've worked with this kind of generic programming in Scala for a while it becomes more or less intuitive, and we'd of course be happy to answer more specific questions about your use case.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the individual pieces that go into creating the end product!

Comment: A bit of a follow-up, out of curiosity: What constrains the relationship between `F` and `I`? In other words, what prevents the use of `wrap` with incompatible types, say for example, `(A, B)` and `(A, B, C) => D`? Is it the fact that I can not get instances of `FnToProduct` / `FnFromProduct` for types which don't line up? What prevents me from creating such a type, accidentally or otherwise? In other words, what differentiates "correct" (or conventionally acceptable) instances of `FnToProduct` / `FnFromProduct`?

Comment: Shapeless will only provide valid instances of these type classes. I suppose you could provide your own invalid ones, but that's the case with any (non-sealed) type class. Why these type classes aren't sealed is a good question—it may just be because that would be inconvenient given the way Shapeless's code generation works. In any case you typically don't worry about accidentally creating invalid instances of type classes like this (and shouldn't be defining your own instances at all).

Comment: For many shapeless typeclasses it's convenient to be able to define one's own instances, e.g. if one had one's own "function-like" class that one wanted to be able to use with this method.

Comment: @lmm I'd probably define my own type class in that situation—you'd have to duplicate a lot of Shapeless's arity-level boilerplate anyway.