# Executing and getting return value of a function wrapped in a context?

Tags: scala, scalaz

I have a function in a context, (in a Maybe / Option) and I want to pass it a value and get back the return value, directly out of the context.

Let's take an example in Scala :

```
scala> Some((x:Int) => x * x)
res0: Some[Int => Int] = Some(<function1>)
```

Of course, I can do

```
res0.map(_(5))
```

to execute the function, but the result is wrapped in the context.

Ok, I could do :

```
res0.map(_(5)).getOrElse(...)
```

but I'm copy/pasting this everywhere in my code (I have a lot of functions wrapped in Option, or worst, in Either...).

I need a better form, something like :

```
res0.applyOrElse(5, ...)
```

Does this concept of 'applying a function in a concept to a value and immediatly returning the result out of the context' exists in FP with a specific name (I'm lost in all those Functor, Monad and Applicatives...) ?

Comment: This is a little like `Kleisli`'s `unliftId`, but instead of a comonad instance you want to provide a default value. I'm not sure off the top of my head whether Scalaz provides a convenient way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `andThen` to move the default from the place where you call the function to the place where you define it:

```
val foo: String => Option[Int] = s => Some(s.size)
val bar: String => Int = foo.andThen(_.getOrElse(100))
```

This only works for `Function1`, but if you want a more generic version, Scalaz provides functor instances for `FunctionN`:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

val foo: (String, Int) => Option[Int] = (s, i) => Some(s.size + i)
val bar: (String, Int) => Int = foo.map(_.getOrElse(100))
```

This also works for `Function1`—just replace `andThen` above with `map`.

More generally, as I mention above, this looks a little like `unliftId` on `Kleisli`, which takes a wrapped function `A => F[B]` and collapses the `F` using a comonad instance for `F`. If you wanted something that worked generically for `Option`, `Either[E, ?]`, etc., you could write something similar that would take a `Optional` instance for `F` and a default value.

Comment: This is what I was expecting (more or less). Thank you.
Peter Neyens answer was really interesting too, so I'm selecting this one as the accepted answer, but Peter one is worth considering too.

Answer (score 1):

You could write something like `applyOrElse` using `Option.fold`.

> fold[B](ifEmpty: ⇒ B)(f: (A) ⇒ B): B

```
val squared = Some((x:Int) => x * x)
squared.fold { 
  // or else = ifEmpty
  math.pow(5, 2).toInt
}{
  // execute function
  _(5)
}
```

---

Using Travis Browns recent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31481836/scala-function-tupled-and-function-untupled-equivalent-for-variable-arity-or-c/31485711#31485711) on another question, I was able to puzzle together the following `applyOrElse` function. It depends on Shapeless and you need to pass the arguments as an `HList` so it might not be exactly what you want.

```
def applyOrElse[F, I <: HList, O](
  optionFun: Option[F],
  input: I,
  orElse: => O
)(implicit
  ftp: FnToProduct.Aux[F, I => O]
): O = optionFun.fold(orElse)(f => ftp(f)(input))
```

Which can be used as :

```
val squared = Some((x:Int) => x * x)
applyOrElse(squared, 2 :: HNil, 10)
// res0: Int = 4

applyOrElse(None, 2 :: HNil, 10)
// res1: Int = 10

val concat = Some((a: String, b: String) => s"$a $b")
applyOrElse(concat, "hello" :: "world" :: HNil, "not" + "executed")
// res2: String = hello world
```

Comment: I have added an `applyOrElse` function using shapeless. Somebody better versed in shapeless might be able to improve it ...

Comment: This may be overkill since the OP doesn't specify that support for `FunctionN` is necessary, and even then it's probably a little cleaner to use something like a `Functor` instance for `FunctionN`.

Comment: Thank you both for this interesting approach ; FunctionN could be required sometimes (I wanted to start with a simple case), so this is definetly usefull. But for most of my cases, this is overkill, yes ! :)

Answer (score 0):

The getOrElse is most logical way to do it. In regards to copy/pasting it all over the place - you might not be dividing your logic up on the best way. Generally, you want to defer resolving your Options (or Futures/etc) in your code until the point you need to have it unwrapped. In this case, it seems more sensible that your function takes in an an Int and returns an Int, and you map your option where you need the result of that function.